# Where should an adverb come in a sentence?

Tags: word-order

If both of the sentences below are correct, does the position of the adverb change the meaning (slightly), or perhaps the register of the sentence?

> 1. The superior man thinks always of virtue.
> 2. The superior man always thinks of virtue.

Comment: The first is a hair odd, but "correct" by most measures.  The effect of it is mostly to emphasize "always", but a lot depends on context.

Comment: Both are fairly rarefied to start with, but the first variant is literati-level.